# Xcode 14 NavigationPath – two views pushed onto nav stack when multiple links in form section

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode14, navigationpath

- Create new SwiftUI project
- Replace ContentView with the code below
- Tap either link.
- Both views are pushed onto the nav stack

```swift
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navigationPath = NavigationPath()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.navigationPath) {
            Form {
                Section {
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink(value: 1) {
                            Text("Location")
                        }

                        NavigationLink(value: 2) {
                            Text("Category")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { route in
                switch route {
                case 1: Text("Location")
                case 2: Text("Category")
                default: Text("Unknown")
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Home")
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I would only expect the tapped item to be pushed into the stack.

Comment: the `Form` seems to interfere with the stack working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `VStack` solves the problem